# PermissionFlagsBits ManageMessages Not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I dont know why `setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageMessages)` do not work. Can You help me ? The code is in discordJs V14 !

```
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('clear')
    .setDescription('Clear Channel')
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageMessages)
    .setDMPermission(false)
    .addIntegerOption(option => 
        option.setName('number')
            .setDescription('Nombre de messages que vous voulez supprimer.')
            .setRequired(true)
    ),

    async execute(interaction, client) {

        var number = interaction.options.getInteger('number');

        if(number >= 1 && number <= 100){
            interaction.channel.bulkDelete(number);
            interaction.reply({content: number + ' messages ont correctement étés supprimés !', ephemeral: true})
        }
        else {
            interaction.reply({ content: 'Le nombre de message a supprimer doit être entre 1 et 100.', ephemeral: true})
        }

    
  },
};
```

Comment: What does _'do not work"_ mean?

Comment: this means that anyone can run the command without the ManageMessages permission

Comment: If you bot has the `ManageMessages` permission then you need not to check for user I believe, you can directly bulk delete upto 100 messages at a time